# How to set Logo for mail sender with the help of nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

In my nodejs project, I'm using [**nodemailer**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) to send mail With the following options:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: MY_HOST,
    port: 587,
    auth: MY_AUTH,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
})
var mailOptions = {
    from: {
        name: "MY NAME",
        address: MY_ADDRESS
    },
    to: 'rayan.plus@gmail.com',
    subject: `MY_SUBJECT`,
    html: MY_CONTENT
}
```

How to set logo for sender mail in mailOptions. I searched a lot and did not find any solution.

[image]